# Java: Split line by Unix new line character

Tags: java

I have this data in my input file `u,9,1,bid\nu,11,5,ask\nq,best_bid\nu,10,2,bid\nq,best_bid\no,sell,1\nq,size,10\nu,9,0,bid\nu,11,0,ask\n`
How can I split it by `\n` so the formatted line will be

```
u,11,5,ask
q,best_bid
u,10,2,bid
q,best_bid
o,sell,1
q,size,10
u,9,0,bid
u,11,0,ask
```

I've already tried `String[] s = line.split("\\n")` but this didnt help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to explain why `line.split("\\n")` doesn't work. See below for a quicker solution.

`"\\n"` [matches a newline](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum). Your file contains literal `\n`s (that is, backslashes followed by the letter "n") instead, so you need to escape the backslash as well.

```
line.split("\\\\n")
```

Then you can join them with a `\n`.

So

```
String joined = String.join("\n", line.split("\\\\n"));
System.out.println(joined);
```

Which outputs

```
u,9,1,bid
u,11,5,ask
q,best_bid
u,10,2,bid
q,best_bid
o,sell,1
q,size,10
u,9,0,bid
u,11,0,ask
```

---

Having said that, if you don't intend to do any intermediate step with the result of splitting the line, you might as well replace the literal `\n` with an actual newline

```
line.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: Wouldn't `line.replace("\\n", "\n")` work just as well?

Comment: @ernest_k well, actually, yes. Let me address that.